# How to hide title, logo and share option on youtube video?

Tags: html, css, hide

I have tried a lot of different codes find on this forum and other websites to mask the top bar : logo, title and share option but no one is working. I really need it to integrate a video on my website. Could you please help me ? I am not a developper, I am not comfortable with codes etc... but I understand html language and I don't know why it is not working.

Exemple of codes tried that didn't work:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DXiZlOnniwA?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&fs=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DXiZlOnniwA?&modestbranding=1&showtitle=0&controls=0" frameborder="0"width="500" height="280"></iframe>
```

Comment: What you are asking seems to be unavailable. Please see this.
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887769/10399001)