# When I embed a YouTube video in Iframe, I want to remove the video title from it

Tags: android, iframe, html5-video

I have done by using showinfo=0 but it has been deprecated.

What is another way to hide video information?

Answer (score 0):

You could use margin-top to hide the title, as they say in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886853/youtube-embed-showinfo-has-been-deprecated)

```
iframe {
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/dyXvbap)