# How to hide controls and info of a embeded youtube video?

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I want to remove all information from the embedded videos like:

1. The title of the videos
2. Share
3. Watch on YouTube
4. Suggested videos
5. Name of the channel

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube alone allows you to do some of these things for example if you go to the video you are wanting to share and you click share and then the embed option you get a few settings.

The main one you will want it the one which says "show player controls" when this is unticked viewers wont be able to skip the video at all but they can still pause / play.

If you want to hide the title card simply add this is to the end of the URL for the video "&showinfo=0" and this should remove that information for you.

As for everything else I am not too sure on so hopefully someone else can help with the remaining parts

Comment: the "showinfo=0" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: so it has here is a stack overflow discussion of people going over a few possigle solutions give these a go 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886853/youtube-embed-showinfo-has-been-deprecated